# What wordpress plugin would sue my needs?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Hello fellow stackoverflowers,

I'm really confused regarding wordpress and i'm trying my best to understand everything.

What i need is a plugin that will make my posts look like portfolio page with images on it, so it's something like:

```
Title1
____________________________
|Text Text Text|Image Image|
|Text Text Text|Image Image|
|Text Text Text|Image Image|
----------------------------
Title2
____________________________
|Text Text Text|Image Image|
|Text Text Text|Image Image|
|Text Text Text|Image Image|
----------------------------
```

I have also asked this question on WP based forums, but noone can actually help me there.

I need it as i have few friends that has no experience in any websites and i would like to make them posting our portfolio jobs easier.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you want post with multiple images?

Comment: Yes, exactly. With modal popup perhaps

Comment: you can do it without plugin..

Answer (score 0):

Try to place below code into your file:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();  ?>
                      <h1 class="entry-title">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    </h1>
                    <div class="entry-content">
    <?php the_content( ); ?>
                        <?php $attachments = get_posts( array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
        'exclude'     => get_post_thumbnail_id()
    ) ); 
 ?><div id="posts">
<ul><?php
    if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {                 
               $thumbimg = wp_get_attachment_link( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail-size', true );
            echo '<li class="thumbnail">' . $thumbimg . '</li>';
        }        
    }
  ?>    </ul>
 </div>
                    </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: I'm not really understanding this, where should i add this code and where should my mates make new posts? Thanks once again.

Comment: you can add code in index.php or file you want to display posts. you just need to upload images from media